# css png sprite animation not responsive working

Tags: animation, png, sprite, internet-explorer-11, responsive

I saw this example and actually it solves a lot of my problems with IE11, but my question now is how can I make this works responsively?. I'd try many options, but I didn't get this example works well with responsive width 100% etc. Any thoughts or suggestions about?

[Sprite animation wobbly / jumping in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710679/sprite-animation-wobbly-jumping-in-ie11)

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Is the same that has been shared on the link, my question is about how to make it responsive in an effective way...